# How to enable\disable dialog views dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, view, dialog

I need your help. my dialog window has 2 radiobuttons. I want to disable or enable some views on this dialog depending on which radiobutton is checked by a user.

my Layout for dialog: inc_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inc_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Название дохода"
        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inc_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:hint="Сумма дохода"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChkBoxIncType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Тип дохода:" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/inc_random"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="Разовый" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/inc_const"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:checked="true"
                 android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
                android:text="Постоянный" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
         android:id="@+id/DataPick1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_gravity="top"
         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
         android:text="Начало периода:" 
         android:enabled="false"/>

     <EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="DD"
    android:enabled="false" >
     </EditText>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_month"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MM" 
    android:enabled="false">
    </EditText>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_year"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"  
    android:text="YYYY" >
    </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_period"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
     android:text="Каждые Х дней" >

        </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Building of this Dialog:

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        adb.setTitle("Добавить доход");
         view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.inc_dialog, null);
        // устанавливаем ее, как содержимое тела диалога
        adb.setView(view) .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }) .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Добавлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });   ;

            return adb.create();
      }
```

onClick function that I call in ACTIVITY

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked (){ 

          switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.inc_const:
                findViewById(R.id.DataPick1).setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case R.id.inc_random:
                findViewById(R.id.DataPick1).setEnabled(false);
                break;
        }
    };
```

If it's needed the whole Activity code. *Income.java*

```
package com.example.pocketbooker;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Income extends Activity{

   LinearLayout view;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Доходы");
        setContentView(R.layout.income_const);

    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.inoutgo, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


    }
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  {
        AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        adb.setTitle("Добавить доход");
         view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.inc_dialog, null);
        // устанавливаем ее, как содержимое тела диалога
        adb.setView(view) .setPositiveButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }) .setNegativeButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Добавлено", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });   ;

            return adb.create();
      }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.plus:
                showDialog(1);
                return true;
             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

     public void onRadioButtonClicked (){ 

          switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.inc_const:
                findViewById(R.id.DataPick1).setEnabled(true);
                break;
            case R.id.inc_random:
                findViewById(R.id.DataPick1).setEnabled(false);
                break;
        }
    };

    }
```

So I want to change a property of a view in my dialog dynamically. How can I do that? How can I call dialog views from my Activity function? 
And sorry for my english, I'm from kazakhstan.
Please, help.

Comment: Initialze Radio Button then check whether it is checked or not enable/disable according

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've made it.

I used DialogFragment

Created separate class Dialog_inc.java for my dialog

```
package com.example.pocketbooker;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class Dialog_inc extends DialogFragment implements OnClickListener {
   EditText POLE;

   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getDialog().setTitle("Добавить Доход");

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inc_dialog, null);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btnYes).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.btnNo).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.inc_const).setOnClickListener(this);
    v.findViewById(R.id.inc_random).setOnClickListener(this);
    POLE=(EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inc_year);
    return v;

  }

  public void onClick(View v) {

      switch(v.getId())
       {case R.id.inc_const: 
           POLE.setEnabled(true);
           break;
       case R.id.inc_random:
           POLE.setEnabled(false);

           break;
       default:
             dismiss();}

  }

  public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onDismiss(dialog);

  }

  public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    super.onCancel(dialog);

  }

}
```

A bit changed my layout for this, added 2 buttons. inc_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inc_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="Название дохода"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inc_value"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:hint="Сумма дохода"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvChkBoxIncType"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Тип дохода:" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/inc_random"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                android:onClick="OnRadio"
                android:text="Разовый" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/inc_const"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="9dp"
                android:onClick="OnRadio"
                android:checked="true"
                android:text="Постоянный" />

        </RadioGroup>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DataPick1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:text="Начало периода:" 
             />
        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_day"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="DD"  >

        </EditText><EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_month"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="MM" 

    >

        </EditText><EditText
            android:id="@+id/inc_year"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="YYYY" >

        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inc_period"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
     android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"
    android:text="Каждые Х дней" >

        </EditText>
        <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnYes"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:text="yes">
</Button>
<Button
 android:id="@+id/btnNo"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_margin="10dp"
 android:text="no">
</Button>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I call this dialog like this. Income.class

```
package com.example.pocketbooker;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class Income extends Activity{

   LinearLayout view;
   DialogFragment dlg1;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTitle("Доходы");
        setContentView(R.layout.income_const);
        dlg1 = new Dialog_inc();
    }
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.inoutgo, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
            }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.plus:
                dlg1.show(getFragmentManager(), "dlg1");
                return true;
             default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Of course it's not a beautiful code now. But I hope it can help someone. Thanks everyone for responding

Answer (score 1):

Because DataPicker is inside Dialog layout so you need to pass user selected `RadioButton` id in onCreateDialog method. try it as:

```
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)  {
        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup1);
            AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            adb.setTitle("Добавить доход");
             view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
                .inflate(R.layout.inc_dialog, null);
    int radioBtnid = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    // get DatePicker
    DatePicker datepick1=(DatePicker)view.findViewById(R.id.DataPick1);
    if(radioBtnid==R.id.inc_const){
      //Enable DataPick1 
      datepick1.setEnabled(true);
    }else if(radioBtnid==R.id.inc_random){
       // Disable DataPick1 
       datepick1.setEnabled(false);
    }

 //your code ...
}
```

Comment: It didn't help. It's executed only 1 time..and then nothing happens

Answer (score 1):

First of all pass in the View as argument to your onRadioButtonClicked() method since it is necessary for onClick method mentioned in XML layout.
Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was clicked)

Also Check if the view that was passed is whether selected or not by calling isChecked() method. Your final code might look like below:

```
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
// Is the button now checked?
boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

// Check which radio button was clicked
switch(view.getId()) {
    case R.id.inc_const:
        if (checked)
            // Do the necessary things here if inc_const is selected
            findViewById(R.id.DataPick1).setEnabled(true);
        break;
    case R.id.inc_random:
        if (checked)
            // Put the code necessary if the random is checked
            findViewById(R.id.DataPick1).setEnabled(false);
        break;
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm new here, so I hope that's how people answer here. Unfortunately, it didn't help. ((